# k-dimensional central extension of Lie algebras

Tags: lie-algebras

Does the phrase "a k-dimensional central extension of the Lie algebra L" mean "a central extension of L by a k-dimensional Lie algebra"?

I cannot find any textbook which mentions to that phrase.

Many thanks for considering my stupid question!

Comment: It is impossible to know. Use the context to decide.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does
see this for more understanding

[This 1](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiS-6iHvKrXAhUFSRoKHfHmB2gQFghFMAU&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mathematik.uni-muenchen.de%2F~schotten%2FLNP-cft-pdf%2F04_978-3-540-68625-5_Ch04_23-08-08.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3BNCZ_ckcpkij4ZDb0vAuv)  (*Schottenloher, M.: Central Extensions of Lie Algebras and Bargmann’s Theorem. Lect. Notes
Phys. 759, 63-73 (2008)*)

[This 2](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0011224) (*Characteristically nilpotent Lie algebras: a survey*, by J.
 M. Ancochea and R. Campoamor)

[This simple for physics](http://math.univ-lille1.fr/~gmt/PaperFolder/CentralExtensions.pdf)  (*Central extension and physics*,
by G.M. Tuynman and W.A.J.J. Wiegerinck)

Comment: The URL was edited now .